# Access class methods from Javascript on an aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to access class methods using Javascript in an aspx page.  I would like to assign the value that is returned by the class method to a Javascript variable.  I've added the import statement to the aspx page but I'm not sure about the class method syntax.  I would like to do something similar to the code below in JavaScript:

```
Dim h As New Helper() 
var newId = h.GetID
```

Can someone help explain how to do this correctly with JavaScript from an aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods will let you access `static` methods in a code-behind class, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

> Note: The method must be decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute and the method must be `static`, thus the method has no access to any of the page class members or controls.

Now in your client script, you can use the jQuery `.ajax()` function to make an asynchronous request to the server, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YourPageName.aspx/GetDate",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            // Store result in a variable here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is there any way to use var newId = '<%=h.GetID%>' in the client script instead of using page methods?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.